# How to shape td bgcolor

Tags: html, css

can anyone help me change the shape of my  bgcolor more like a `rounded` not a rectangular shape...I'm just not that expert in `css` can anyone help me please.

[image]

Comment: use border-radius in your css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with

```
table { border-collapse: separate; }
td{
    border-radius : 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a CSS property called `border-radius`

A very thorough walkthrough can be found at http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-radius/

Example:

```
table td {

  /* Safari 3-4, iOS 1-3.2, Android 1.6- */
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px; 

  /* Firefox 1-3.6 */
  -moz-border-radius: 4px; 

  /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Safari 5, Chrome, Firefox 4, iOS 4, Android 2.1+ */
  border-radius: 4px; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these to the div that you want rounded for full cross browser compatibility. Obviously you can change the values. The higher the value the more bend in the curve.

```
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
```